# Add Appointment to exchange programatically without EWS

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Evening all,

I have been doing some work for a client which involves adding appointments into a Google calendar, today I have been told that they are not going to be using Google any more and will be using the calendar available through exchange, They are using an off site instance of exchange hosted by a third party, as best as I can tell at the moment they do not have EWS enabled (I am awaiting confirmation on this).

So I am weighing up my options at the moment, if the third party comes back and says that EWS is not available I need some other way of getting the appointments into exchange.

Right, some background about the app:
C# ASP.NET WebForms site (.net 4.5) hosted on a dedicated server.

Any suggestions that you may have would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use MAPI, but if the 3rd party really does have EWS blocked/disabled (seems unlikely), then it's very doubtful they have the necessary ports open for MAPI access from outside their network.

Comment: Thanks, its something else to try!
Im still waiting to hear back from them about EWS.